# Sprite animation jumps at the begining

Tags: css, animation, sprite

I am creating a sprite animation of a treasure chest opening. I have made 7 stages placed next to each other on a single "png" format image. It works fine with the following code but for some reason at the beginning of the animation the image jumps up. I thought it was a problem with the image and that the first stage may have been a little lower than the others. This was not the case, so I am left not knowing what the problem is. Can anyone enlighten me to what the problem is?

```
body {
text-align: center;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -3600px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -3600px; } 
}

@keyframes wink {
    from { background-position: 0px; }
    to { background-position: -3600px; }
}


.chest {
    background-image: url("file://///FILESERVER/scratch/Sean/sprite2.png");
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
}

.chest:hover {    
    -webkit-animation: wink 2.5s steps(6, end) 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: wink 2.5s steps(6, end) 1 forwards;
    animation: wink 2.5s steps(6, end) 1 forwards;
}
```

Comment: Please create an example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I can't because the sprite png is saved locally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because you have not set an initial background position so when the animation starts the background images is jumping up.

```
.chest {
    background-image: url("file://///FILESERVER/scratch/Sean/sprite2.png");
background-position: 0 0;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
}
```

This should fix it